# Embedding a website within a website with 100% height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying a website into a page on another website using an Iframe. I've managed to the page to load in. However I need the site within the page to load to the height of the website. Rather than the page of the website it's sat within.

Currently if i set the height to 100% it only shows part of the website as that's the only content on the the page. What I don't want to do is set a height of say 4000px to the embedded website as some of the pages will only have a few images or a few lines of text to display.

I'd just like to know of this is possible.

Code to Iframe -

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Code to object -

```
<object data="http://example.com" type="text/html" height="100%" width="1024px"></object>
```

Comment: The internet hates people like you Josh. Don't be that guy.

Comment: Mind explaining why? I own both of the sites?

Comment: I mind explaining to you. It's **Content Security Policy’**  (https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/content-security-policy/raw-file/tip/csp-specification.dev.html  and it's about providing the web some tools to conter-act content thievery.

Comment: Well like I said, I own both the sites so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can:

```
iframe {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
overflow:auto; /* coz you need vertical and horizontal scrollbars */
}
```

This will work if none of the iframe parents have position other than static (which is default)

you may need the `body {margin:0px; padding:0px;}` too.

Comment: Thank you! Will give this a try now!

Comment: Thanks, seems to have done the trick. I'm actually going to go down a different road and just re-skin the site I was embedding. But thank you as this will come in handy later on.